# Название формы в FormIt в MODx

Tags: cms, modx, formit

Подскажите, как изменить название формы сохраняемой данные с помощью FormIt (AjaxForm) в админ-панели MODx?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Данное поле меняется с помощью &formName=``